# Bounce processing and X-CiviMail-Bounce possible bug?

Tags: civimail, bounce-processing

I am unable to get bounce processing working on more than one Plesk server, and think I may have found a bug in the CRM/Utils/Mail/IncomingMail.php file.

Line 170 sets a regex string with the following code:

```
$rpXHeaderRegex = '/X-CiviMail-Bounce: ' . $emailLocalPart . '(b)' . $twoDigitString . '([0-9a-f]{16})@' . $emailDomain . '/i';
```

The '([0-9a-f]{16})@' part means that it is looking for a 16 digit string which can contain numbers, and the letters a - f.

It is failing to find the string in my bounced mails though, because the 16 digit parts contain letters other than a - f.

If I change the code to '([0-9a-z]{16})@', so it is looking for letters a - z, then bounce processing works properly.

It seems there is a mismatch between the headers Civi is assigning when it sends the mail, and the headers it is looking for when it receives them back as a bounce.

An example of an X-CiviMail-Bounce header in the bounced email is:

```
X-CiviMail-Bounce: bounces+b.86.404.vnqd0g7cqfjrdqqj@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in CiviCRM 5.68+: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28354

Comment: Dang it, I could have save myself several hours of debugging! Mental note, check Github next time. Thanks @Jon G

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis sounds good. Can you please open a pull-request on github with that change so it can be reviewed by Civi developers?